# Java Directory Path - Eclipse vs Windows CMD

Tags: eclipse, cmd

I have a directory - dir1 - that I want to write a file to and some other files I want info from. Running with Eclipse the directory and files are outside the bin folder and works well.

However, when using the command line outside bin it doesn't find the main class, and inside bin

```
java Main.MainClass
```

I can't acess them since it's looking for them inside the bin folder. Since I'll be wanting to run this in other pcs I suppose I can't use absolute paths.

Can I solve this from inside the program? If not, what are other alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the folder to you main class.
Either using arguments or using a properties file

Using arguments:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html

Properties:
http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/

Added:
Another possibility could also be to store files in the user home directory.
System.getProperty("user.home");

See also for common properties:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html

Comment: So for example, in my pc it's C:\...\User\dir, but to run in another I would change the path in the property file to C:\...\Desktop\dir instead of the original in order to change paths?

Comment: Yes the property file has do be changed on every environment to the according value

Comment: Ok, that might be the simpler and best way for my case.